# python auto-scroll to top of print output

Tags: python

I'm outputting quite a lot of data to the screen using the print function (reading from a file and then displaying the full content on screen).

The screen positions itself at the bottom of all the output (waiting for next action from user). Is there any way to auto-position the screen to the start of my print output??

```
def stats():
    # Call function to generate reports - always generate and overwrite (easiest method):
   reports()

   # Now read from reports and display on screen:
   r1 = "task_overview.txt"
   r2 = "user_overview.txt"
   to = open(r1, "r")
   uo = open(r2, "r")
   to_content = to.read()
   uo_content = uo.read()
   print(to_content)  # I'd like screen to "freeze" at the top here until user scrolls down
   print("\n" * 3)
   print(uo_content)
   to.close()
   uo.close()

   option = input("Type '-1' to go back to the Main Menu, or any other key to exit.\n--> ")
   if option == '-1':
      mainMenu()
   else:
      print("Goodbye")
      exit()
```

EDIT: I should have mentioned this is part of a course I am doing, and I HAVE to display the results on screen. Just trying to make it as user-friendly as possible

Comment: You may wish to pipe your output into a pager such as `python main.py | less` or output it to a file

Comment: I should have mentioned this is part of a course I am doing, and I HAVE to display the results on screen. Just trying to make it as user-friendly as possible

Comment: Well either you can try to implement the paging yourself by outputting blocks of data at a time and waiting for user input to continue or you can just use a pager like `less`

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not even python thing. What you can do however is to write your output to a file and at the end display it using i. e. `more` or similar tool.